# Javascript- Iterate through Array values not working - TypeError: DealsController.prototype.a is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make the code below work for not only DealsController.prototype.**showcase** but also DealsController.prototype.**anothermethod2** and **anothermethod**3 ans so on...without repeating the code each time. i am trying to use a loop for this.

Here is the code I want to refactor using maybe a loop:
deal.js

```
var DealsController = Paloma.controller('Deals');

// Handle showcase Deals controller action 'showcase'
DealsController.prototype.showcase = function () {    
            // display basic rule of how the app works then make it disappear after 3 seconds
  $(window).load(function(){
    if ($.cookie("onboarding_modal_shownNX") == null) {
      $.cookie('onboarding_modal_shownNX', 'yes', { expires: 720, path: '/' }); // only show onboading modal once per device
      $('#onboardingModal').modal('show');    
      $('#onboardingModal').fadeTo(3000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
        $(this).remove(); 
      });
    }
  });  

};

 DealsController.prototype.method2 = function () {
            // display basic rule of how the app works then make it disappear after 3 seconds
  $(window).load(function(){
    if ($.cookie("onboarding_modal_shownNX") == null) {
      $.cookie('onboarding_modal_shownNX', 'yes', { expires: 720, path: '/' }); // only show onboading modal once per device
      $('#onboardingModal').modal('show');    
      $('#onboardingModal').fadeTo(3000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
        $(this).remove(); 
      });
    }
  });  

};

 DealsController.prototype.method3 = function () {  
            // display basic rule of how the app works then make it disappear after 3 seconds
  $(window).load(function(){
    if ($.cookie("onboarding_modal_shownNX") == null) {
      $.cookie('onboarding_modal_shownNX', 'yes', { expires: 720, path: '/' }); // only show onboading modal once per device
      $('#onboardingModal').modal('show');    
      $('#onboardingModal').fadeTo(3000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
        $(this).remove(); 
      });
    }
  });  

};
```

I tried with various methods explained here [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) but I get this error for example:

```
deal.js

var DealsController = Paloma.controller('Deals');

var index;
var a = ["showcase", "method2", "method3"];
for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
    console.log(a[index]);

DealsController.prototype.a[index] = function () {



      /* NEW USER ONBOARDING**************************************************
       */ 

      // display basic rule of how the app works then make it disappear after 3 seconds
      $(window).load(function(){
        if ($.cookie("onboarding_modal_shownNX") == null) {
          $.cookie('onboarding_modal_shownNX', 'yes', { expires: 720, path: '/' }); // only show onboading modal once per device
          $('#onboardingModal').modal('show');    
          $('#onboardingModal').fadeTo(3000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
            $(this).remove(); 
          });
        }
      });  

    };
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: DealsController.prototype.a is undefined
```

Comment: Is DealssController(at the first line) a typo?

Comment: yes sorry, correcting it

Comment: You've to use bracket notation to name a properties by values from `a`, i.e. `DealsController.prototype[a[index]] = ...`.

Comment: If you don't want to repeat the code, is there a reason you don't just move it out to its own function and call it from the `DealsController.prototype` methods? I assume there must be *something* that should differentiate them, right?

Comment: Not sure I get you guys. I just want to have the js block to "repeat itself" as if I was writing 3 times the block only difference being the first line : DealsController.prototype.method1, DealsController.prototype.anothermethod, DealsController.prototype.again anothermethod...

Comment: @squint no reason,  i'm just a javascript rookie so know I must not simple REPEAT three times this block where only a very small thing change but i don't know how to do it. thought i would use a loop, that's all

Comment: I'm gonna add inside the question the end result I need so that it's more clear

Comment: That's what @Teemu's solution will do. See how you access the index of `a` using `[index]`? You need to do the same thing to access those three property names on the `.prototype`. so `.prototype[a[index]]`

Comment: @all: thanks Teemu solution is working!

Comment: How come DealsController.prototype.method2 can become DealsController.prototype[a[index]]. i mean the array only inject the string "method2" but not the point "."...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment above from Teemu shows what you're doing incorrectly. But if they're all meant to call the same exact function, it would be simpler to simply assign the same function to all three properties.

```
DealsController.prototype.showcase =
DealsController.prototype.method2 =
DealsController.prototype.method3 = function() {
  $(window).load(function(){
    if ($.cookie("onboarding_modal_shownNX") == null) {
      $.cookie('onboarding_modal_shownNX', 'yes', { expires: 720, path: '/' }); // only show onboading modal once per device
      $('#onboardingModal').modal('show');    
      $('#onboardingModal').fadeTo(3000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
        $(this).remove(); 
      });
    }
  });  
};
```

Or if you want to use a loop, first create the function and then assign it in the loop.

```
function sharedFunc() {
  $(window).load(function(){
    if ($.cookie("onboarding_modal_shownNX") == null) {
      $.cookie('onboarding_modal_shownNX', 'yes', { expires: 720, path: '/' }); // only show onboading modal once per device
      $('#onboardingModal').modal('show');    
      $('#onboardingModal').fadeTo(3000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
        $(this).remove(); 
      });
    }
  });  
};

var index;
var a = ["showcase", "method2", "method3"];
var name;
for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
  name = a[index];
  DealsController.prototype[name] = sharedFunc;
}
```

Comment: it seems so simple. Can it be done ? then why do people use often for this for..in, or freach loops?

Comment: @Mathieu: It's unusual to share the exact same function on a `.prototype`. There could be situations where each version needs to reference a unique, scoped variable. In that case, `.forEach()` or a regular loop that also calls another function to create a closure are needed.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll just use then your first solution. My mind was to closed on finding a way to loop. But I learnt anyway sth about loops in the process. thanks